# Figma to Python-tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, figma

I am new in Figma and I have created a design in Figma but I couldn’t get the codes.

Where should I enter the URL and token?

Probably it is a simple question but I couldn’t solve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The chance of someone knowing how both `figma` and `tkinter` work is low. Can you describe what you have? I have no experience with `figma` but no part of `tkinter` deals with urls or anything internet connected.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It is easily done by using tkinter designer. Thanks